# Chrome Android Mobile missing CSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, mobile

I recently re-developed my old website with bootstrap and new css. I have already uploaded to the server, and the new responsiveness is great. However, for some odd reason when I go to my Motorola Moto Z Android phone and view with Google Chrome v58, the website seems to be missing all CSS, including both bootstrap and the web page style.css.

I have tried emulating on PC with both chrome and Firefox's mobile response testing and it appears fine on pc. I even installed Firefox on my phone to test. Firefox works great and displays everything correctly. Haven't tried Safari, since I don't have an iPhone. I'm not sure as to why chrome wont display the content correctly, and not having web dev tools on the mobile device itself is making things difficult.

I am not sure if there is a memory limit or caching problem with chrome.

If anyone has a solution or encountered the problem I would appreciate the help.
The website is http://www.zeroviolet.com